# DB2 SQL Statement for Inserting new data and updating existing data

Tags: sql, db2

I've found a lot of near misses on this question.  So many similar, but not quite right, scenarios.  No doubt my ignorance will shine here.

Using DB2 and a shred of knowledge, my scenario is as follows:

On a table, insert a row of data if a given value is not present in a given column, or update the corresponding row if the value **is** present.

I have a table

```
id, bigint, not nullable
ref,varchar, nullable
```

I am not sure if a MERGE is the correct path here as most examples and thorough discussions all seem to revolve around merging one table into another.  I'm simply gathering user input and either adding it or updating it.  It seems like it should be really simple.

I'm using jdbc and prepared statements to get this done.

Is MERGE the correct way to do this?

When testing my query in DB2 Control Center, I run up against

> "No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a
>   query is an empty table"

or a variety of other errors depending on how I structure my MERGE. Here's what I have presently.

```
merge into table1 as t1
using (select id from table1 group by id) as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
when matched then update set t1.ref = 'abc'
when not matched then insert (t1.id, t1.ref) values (123, 'abc');
```

If I were to *instead* compose an **update** followed by an **insert**; for new data the insert runs and the update fails, and for existing data they both succeed resulting in bad data in the table, e.g. two identical rows.

The desired result is if on initial use with the values:

```
id = 1
ref = a
```

a new row is added.  On subsequent use if the values change to:

```
id = 1
ref = b
```

the row with id = 1 is updated.  Subsequent uses would follow the same rules.

Please let me know how I can phrase this question better.

**Update** id is not an automatic incrementing key.  It's an external key that will be unique but not every thing we are referencing will need a related row in the table I'm attempting to update.  This table is rather unstructured on its own but is part of a larger data model.

Comment: Since T2 contains each `id` from `table1`, it's not clear how the `when not matched` condition could ever be expected to be possible. Is that the **exact** `MERGE` statement that gave the error?

Comment: Assuming ID is an auto incrementing primary key, you shouldn't be passing it in during an insert.  Also with an auto primary key, you should have another unique key defined.  If you can insert "bad data" there your table isn't defined right.

Comment: @user2338816 - that is not exactly the same query.  I changed the names of the tables to make it easier to read, but it maps 100% to what I am actually using.  I agree with your comment and tried changing the on (condition) to compare to the supplied id but that produced anomalous results as well.  What you are saying makes sense but because it didn't work, my question above is germane: is MERGE even the right way to approach this use case?

Comment: Is it SQL0100W with SQLSTATE = 02000? The message text is useful, but actual SQL message Id and SQLSTATE are much better. Without seeing the actual statement (unless the example statement gives the same message/state and is accompanied by all example definitions), everything is going to be guesswork, possibly unrelated. DB2 version/release and platform should also be given.

Comment: The question has been answered but to answer your question, the SQLSTATE =  02000 the way I had been trying it.  Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled by your query. Reading the text makes me suspect that you want something like this:

```
merge into table1 as t1
using ( values (123, 'abc') ) as t2 (id, ref)
    on t1.id = t2.id
when matched then update 
    set t1.ref = t2.ref
when not matched then 
    insert (id, ref) values (t2.id, t2.ref);
```

Is that correct?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Thank you. I can see from your answer that I did not grasp he proper use of most of this structure!  Wish I could give you some "saved my bacon" up-votes as well.

Comment: @Lennart how do it add table2 value instead user value in line 2

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan, do you mean selecting values from a second table?

Comment: @Lennart  Yes!. Can you help me with Example

Comment: replace `values (123, 'abc')` with `select id, ref from table2 where ...`